# Can't get values to show in table view cell from API

Tags: swift, rest, api, tableview

I've been trying to get some data I'm calling from an api to reflect into table view controller cells. So far I am a able to get the correct header lines to reflect but the sublines are returning blanks. I have checked the REST all call it does contain values.

```
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! AreaDemandCellTableViewCell

        if indexPath.section == 0 {
            cell.headLine.text = Constants.AreaDemand.headers[indexPath.row];
            cell.subLine.text = self.hdrSubline(row: indexPath.row);
        }
        return cell
    }

    private func hdrSubline(row:Int) -> String {
        switch row {
        case 0:
            return self.areaDemand?.totalForSale?.description ?? "-"
        case 1:
            return self.areaDemand?.averageSale?.description ?? "-"
        case 2:
            return self.areaDemand?.turnover?.description ?? "-"
        case 3:
            return self.areaDemand?.daysOnMarket?.description ?? "-"
        case 4:
            return self.areaDemand?.demandRating?.description ?? "-"
        default:
            return "-"
        }
    }
```

I believe the area where the api data should be called into the table view cell is here and this is where it's appearing blank:

```
    private func hdrSubline(row:Int) -> String {
        switch row {
        case 0:
            return self.areaDemand?.totalForSale?.description ?? "-"
        case 1:
            return self.areaDemand?.averageSale?.description ?? "-"
        case 2:
            return self.areaDemand?.turnover?.description ?? "-"
        case 3:
            return self.areaDemand?.daysOnMarket?.description ?? "-"
        case 4:
            return self.areaDemand?.demandRating?.description ?? "-"
        default:
            return "-"
        }
    }
```

and here is what the table view cell looks like when the app is running:
[image]

Comment: does `self.areaDemand?.totalForSale?.description` variables have proper value, check it by printing.

Comment: How does `self.areaDemand` get set to the right thing?

Comment: You cannot use an API call to populate a cell directly in `cellForRowAt`. The call to `cellForRowAt` returns the cell immediately, but the API call is asynchronous and returns the data later.

Comment: what does your  'numberOfSections' and 'numberOfRowsInSection' method returning ?

Comment: @matt what's odd is that I was able to implement a similar call in other table  view using a different api yet its playing up here. It's looking like its returning empty data as opposed to pulling the correct data from the api. I've made a note of your suggestion for future projects. Thanks

Comment: I don't really care what you were doing elsewhere or whether it seemed to work; it's wrong. For one thing, you would be calling the API every time the user scrolls, even if the user has already seen this cell before and we already downloaded this info a moment ago. So you'd be thrashing the network and the user's battery unnecessarily. The correct procedure is to download the data in the background _into the data modal_ and just reload the table view directly if needed.